# Dynamic Model in Django from fields data in another model

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a project where I have 2 models model

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    ...

class CustomerProperty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    type = models.CharField(...)
    code = models.CharField(...)
```

The `CustomerProperty` table has rows inside based on a parquet file (created at database init, not changed later on). For column in the parquet file, `CustomerProperty` has a row with column name from parquet as `name` in the table.

Now for some other purpose, I need to copy over all the data in the parquet file inside the db. So, for each row in the `CustomerProperty` table, this new table will have a column (plus one column for foreign key to `Customer`) so I can run filters based on property values. This will also be copied over at db init and not change later on, so it is an unmanaged django model.

I can't find any good docs on this, how to create a django model dynamically or how to add fields to that model dynamically. I don't need it to be managed, no need of migrations or django admin view support. I only need it to work with django ORM and be able to join and filter on it.

I've read the docs and didn't find much. Most of the answers talk about why this is a bad idea but I don't see any other way of solving my problem (I have few other tables joined together to run a complex query and I need to do further filtration based on these properties and support pagination.

Comment: Maybe your best shot with this is to use raw SQL queries. I think that Django models are not made to do that. However, if I was in your place, that would make me think that the database design could be done in a better way.

Comment: Another idea, maybe try the `JSONField` instead of defining a whole model. For each row in the `CustomerProperty`, you could add a key to the JSON.

Comment: Hmmm... yeah its not the best solution and later on I plan to move this to an ETL and denormalize in some other solution but can't do it right now. JSONField won't let me filter on columns though, right?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to filter on columns in the json field. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)